DPDK network sessions data store
I try to create traffic analyzer using DPDK. It receives copy of all network traffic and should not send answers in TX quque.
I have adapter which receives traffic (DPDK primary process), and a few analyzers (DPDK secondary processes). Adapter send packets via ring queue from DPDK framework.
To analyze network sessions I need to store some hash table with sessions data in shared memory.
Does DPDK has API to create it? What is usually used for this?
I'm considering DPDK Hash Library with RCU Library. There may be a situation that two different secondary analyzer processes simultaneously subtract data from a shared memory and a states race will happen. I would like to avoid this
